# Phonegap build android disable home/power/softkeys (kiosk mode type application)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm currently using Phonegap Build (3.7) to build a simple (but useful) mobile application.

The application I am making will need to simulate a kiosk mode type application, so the device will only be used with this application and nothing else (we are providing the devices).

I have actually managed to disable the back key but cannot figure out how to disable the home and task menu softkeys. Does anyone have an idea if

1. Is this possible
2. Is this possible with PhoneGap Build?
3. how would you go about implementing this with PhoneGap Build?

I've had suggestions that you could create a custom Java file and include this as a phonegap build plugin (but i've no experience of any java programming)

any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: how did you disable the back button?

Comment: Usability wise you should not disable them. Think how would user exit from the app. However if you still want you should hide the bar with fullscreen activity.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the home button, however here is how to disable the back button:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Cordova/Phonegap events page has events listed for system buttons here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html

Comment: Thanks for this dbcole but as mentioned I already have managed to disable with back button (with the above code)

Comment: Sorry I saw you mention the task menu button, which looks to be the "menubutton" event. Home button is not able to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can disable home button. Android does not support this.

Comment: Is there any documentation that proves this is the case? If so how do applications already in the app store manage to do this?

Answer (score 0):

this plugin is disable all action buttons:

https://github.com/guatedude2/cordova-plugin-kiosk-launcher

save for "backbutton", but it might be disabled as mentioned with below answers